# Cannot inject HttpClient in typed client while using with IMediatR library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, mediatr

According to examples provided by ASP.NET Core 2.2 documentation in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients), it is possible to inject HttpClient to a typed clients (service-classes) by adding the following line to Startup.cs:

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddHttpClient<GitHubService>();
```

From controller class it will look like (from now I will use GitHub as a simplification for a domain model):

```
// GitHubController.cs
public class GitHubController : Controller
{
    private readonly GitHubService _service;
    public GitHubController(GitHubService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

However, I use [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) library in my project, so my project structure looks a bit different. I have 2 projects - **GitHubFun.Api, GitHubFun.Core** - ASP.NET Core 2.2 API project and .NET Core 2.2 class library respectively.

My controller:

```
// GitHubController.cs
public class GitHubController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    public GitHubController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator= mediator;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetGitHubRepositoryInfo(
        GetGitHubRepositoryCommand command)
    {
         _mediator.Send(command);
    }
}
```

And my handler class:

```
// GetGitHubRepositoryHandler.cs
public class GetGitHubRepositoryHandler : 
    IRequestHandler<GetGitHubRepositoryCommand , GetGitHubRepositoryCommandResult>
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public GetGitHubRepositoryHandler(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

When I make HTTP request and call an API method, it successfully injects IMediator, but throws an exception on **_mediator.Send(command)** line.

Exception body:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[IDocs.CryptoServer.Core.Commands.ExtractX509Command,IDocs.CryptoServer.Core.Commands.ExtractX509CommandResult]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'IDocs.CryptoServer.Core.Handlers.ExtractX509CommandHandler'

(ExtractX509CommandHandler - is just a real domain model, instead of GetGitHubRepositoryHandler).

It seems that ASP.NET Core DI cannot resolve DI and inject HttpClient to handler.

My Startup.cs has the following lines:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ExtractX509CommandHandler>();
services.AddMediatR(
       typeof(Startup).Assembly, 
       typeof(ExtractX509CommandHandler).Assembly);
```

Comment: Sounds like it wants you to register the handler itself (i.e. `GetGitHubRepositoryHandler`). Have you done that?

Comment: Or actually, it may be an issue with `ExtractX509CommandHander`. Does that take `HttpClient` as dependency? If so, did you register a typed client for that?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, yes, I've already registered HttpClient as dependency. And services.AddMediatR(
       typeof(Startup).Assembly, 
       typeof(ExtractX509CommandHandler).Assembly) encapsulates registration for ExtractX509CommandHandler too.

Comment: No. You misunderstand. If `ExtractX509CommandHandler` takes `HttpClient` as dependency, then you need `services.AddHttpClient<ExtractX509CommandHandler>()` as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, yeah, I've already added  services.AddHttpClient<ExtractX509CommandHandler>(). The line services.AddHttpClient<GitHubService>() in my question is just a simplification of this class I made for easy understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. For some reasons, in this case we need to pass IHttpClientFactory from Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll instead of HttpClient to handler class. I just changed one line, it was:

```
public GetGitHubRepositoryHandler(HttpClient httpClient)
```

and now:

```
public GetGitHubRepositoryHandler(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
```

and now it works as it should. I don't know why it works, so it will be perfect, if someone could explain what is the difference between injecting IHttpClientFactory  and HttpClient to the class.

Comment: Did you find a reason for this and what the difference is?

Comment: AddHttpClient<T> registers your service T at the same time. In this case, AddMediatR also does that, so now you get registrations mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

I'm in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

My handler class :

```
public class GetProductsListQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetProductsListQueryModel, IEnumerable<Product>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public GetProductsListQueryHandler(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
```

You need to implement your HttpClient in your Startup like this :

```
services.AddHttpClient<IRequestHandler<GetProductsListQueryModel,IEnumerable<Product>>, GetProductsListQueryHandler>();
```

And it works! ;)